# Поиск пользовательской строки по нескольким записям в Rails

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня выводится список пользователей в таком виде `Test1, Test2 (Test3)` где

`Test1` - это имя пользователя,

`Test2` - это фамилия пользователя,

`Test3` - это никнейм пользователя.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать правильный поиск в БД? Желательно, чтобы я мог сделать поиск именно по этой строке, а не по отдельному полю, если нет, то подскажите пожалуйста наиболее лучший вариант. Благодарю.

Comment: Можно конкатенировать строку в нужном формате, но лучше искать по никнейму, который должен быть уникальным в БД.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko конкатенация подошла, по никнейму что мне искать, если пользователь в строку поиска ввел только имя.

Comment: это уже дополнительное условие, которого нет в техзадании. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.

Для поиска записи сразу по нескольким полям я использую библиотеку [scoped_search](https://github.com/wvanbergen/scoped_search):

1) Добавляем библиотеку в Gemfile

```
gem 'scoped_search'
```

2) Устанавливаем ее

```
bundle install
```

3) Добавляем в модель `User` строку с перечнем полей, по которым будем искать

```
scoped_search on: [:last_name, :first_name, :nikname]
```

4) Выполняем поиск записи

```
User.search_for("Иванов ivanov")
```

Допускается использовать метод *search_for* в цепочке методов

```
User.some_filter1.some_filter2.search_for("Иванов ivanov")
```

Comment: скорее ваш пример не сработает, если я введу эту строку `Test1, Test2 (Test3)`